# Timestamp in header as Byte array to DateTime

Tags: c#, vb.net, timestamp

So i'm currently stuck at something "simple". I get packets from a third party that are a fixed length of 1024 bytes. This comprises 24 bytes of packet header and 1000 bytes of payload data. In order to get the Timestamp i have to look at a certain index. The Timestamp is noted in seconds since januari 2000, it is at postion 8 and 4 bytes long and the milliseconds are on position 5 and 3 bytes long. Example of the real deal:
[image]

So far it's easy. Now i want to retrieve the values so i can convert in to a DateTime object so i can calculate stuff.

The timestamp as totalseconds since januari 2000 is easy:

```
'TimestampS_F is an byte array of 24 bytes long.

''' <summary>
''' Convert the total seconds since 1-1-2000 to the UTC time
''' </summary>
Private Function ConvertTimestampString(TimestampS_F As Byte()) As String
    Return New DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(BitConverter.ToUInt32(TimestampS_F, 8)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:ffff") '.AddMilliseconds(BitConverter.ToUInt32(TimestampS_F, 5))
End Function
```

But know the milliseconds timestamp, this where i'm stuck since the value is 3 bytes long so i cannot convert it to a Uint32 or 16. What would be the right conversion for this?

**EDIT:**
I now know what creates the Timestamp. It's a Spartan Chip and as the document says the Timestamp is as follow: S8 A Adjustment for timezones in half-hours (note this is signed) U24 F Fractional seconds U32 S Seconds since 00:00:00 1st Jan 2000 in GMT F / (2 ^ 24) is the fraction of seconds, so the total time is S + (A*30*60) + (F / (2^24))

**EDIT 25-08-2017:**

Didn't had any time to resume this topic until today. I still am stuck but i managed to get some more documentation. Which is al follow:

```
DWORD tsFractionalAndAdjustment; // Timestamp - first 8 bits are our GMT adjustment in half-hours. signed char format
                                 // Timestamp - next 24 bits are the fractional part of the timestamp.

DWORD tsSeconds;      // Timestamp - Seconds since Jan 2000
```

Now looking at the sample array above and more info from the documentation it turns out we have to start at byte 4 to 8. Then the first 8 bits are used GMT offset en the last 24 bits for the fractional seconds where we have to apply the formula: F / (2 ^ 24). However how can this be done in C# or VB.net? i know the `<<` or `>>` operators but can't find any good explanation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not coded as milliseconds then. My previous answer is void. You'll get the milliseconds part using the formula (F*1000)/(2^24). Read the bytes 5-8 in a UInt32, then

```
ms = ((ui32 & 0xffffff) * 1000.0) / (2 ^ 24)
```

gives you the milliseconds. This is a float expression, the calculation doesn't fit in UInt32.

EDIT:

In your example:

A = 0 //no timezone adjustments, time is GMT (byte 4)

S = 32*16777216 + 72*65536 + 19*256 + 203 = 541594571 //whole seconds, more than 17 years as expected (bytes 8-11)

F = 57*65536 + 29*256 + 96 = 3743072 //represents fractional seconds (bytes 5-7)

F*1000 //represents whole and fractional milliseconds

milliseconds = F*1000/(2^24) = 223,1044769287109375

A C# code of the calculation would be:

```
UInt32 A = TimestampS_F[4] * 30 * 60; // zone adjustment in seconds
UInt32 S = BitConverter.ToUInt32(TimestampS_F, 8); // whole seconds
UInt32 F = BitConverter.ToUInt32(TimestampS_F, 5); // byte 5-8 (highest byte not needed)
double ms = ((double)(F & 0xffffff) * 1000) / Math.Pow(2, 24); // milliseconds (cut highest byte, do conversion to milliseconds)
DateTime dt = New DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(A + S).AddMilliseconds(ms); // decoded result in local time
```

Don't use bit-shift operators. You'll lose fractional milliseconds.

Comment: Did you succeed?

Comment: Hey Janos, It's bene a while (quit busy) Today i picked up this topic and still having difficulties. However i do have retrieved more documentation, see the edit it first post

Answer (score 0):

I'd try Int16.

Looking at your real example it seems impossible that bytes 5-7 contain a real value of milliseconds. The range should be 0-999 that fits in Int16 and the highest byte should be 0. Which is not.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I'd tried it with no luck. However i know what creates the Timestamp. It's a Spartan Chip and as the document says the Timestamp is as follow: `S8 A Adjustment for timezones in half-hours (note this is signed)
U24 F Fractional seconds
U32 S Seconds since 00:00:00 1st Jan 2000 in GMT
F / (2 ^ 24) is the fraction of seconds, so the total time is S + (A*30*60) + (F / (2^24))` Also tried this but cannot convert the value to a DateTime object..